# How to return vector of pointers (and ownership) C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, smart-pointers

I have a factory method that creates a bunch of objects and returns pointers to them. Ownership of the objects transfers to the caller:

```
std::vector<animal*> create_zoo();
```

This works, but is prone to memory leaks.

```
auto zoo = create_zoo();
```

The vector is on the stack and gets cleaned up automatically, the contained objects are not.

Objects of various sub-types are returned. Returing values instead of pointers won't do.

I was thinking to use

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<animal> > create_zoo();
```

but `unique_ptr` don't have copy semantics and I return the `vector` by value, which, in theory, creates a copy.

I could put the `vector` on the heap to avoid that

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<animal> > > create_zoo();
```

but this is getting ridiculous.

This should work too:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<animal> > create_zoo();
```

This would work, but it doesn't really transfer ownership. The caller has to assume that there might be other pointers to the objects.

I'm open to suggestions. doesn't need to be `std::vector`. I'm just looking for a good way of implementing a factory that returns ownership of several objects with modern c++. I'm avoiding boost for now. I'm trying to explore the new c++11 stuff.

Comment: You can also re-consider whether you need the animal objects to be allocated as pointers. `std::vector<animal>` may also work for your purposes. The animal objects will be allocated with the vector and will move around with it after move operations.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<animal>>` will work fine : returning a function-local value will move it, not copy it (or only if moving is not available).

Comment: Hmm.. Wouldn't that imply that my code is then dependent on the compiler's ability to perform the "Return Value Optimization"? I understand that all relevant compilers have it implemented, but I'm not sure if they actually guarantee to perform it in all situations. Is this standard practise?

Comment: @Stefan no, that's not RVO. RVO would remove the function-local altogether, and use the one on the caller's side in its place. this is about `return` move-constructing the temmporary returned object (if RVO failed beforehand).

Comment: That's the bit I was missing! Returning to c++ after 6 years of Python. I feel both rusty and spoiled. Going to read up on this "move" stuff. thanks!

Comment: @Quentin Technically it will (or can) *elide* the function local, not remove it. (Elision is standard-permitted process of *merging object identity* in certain (standard-described) cases.  All the objects exist, but now their names (if they have them) all refer to the same object with one combined lifetime.)

Comment: @Stefan Also, there will be something called "guaranteed copy elision" in C++17 that, I believe, will essentially force RVO-like behavior even without move or copy constructors.

Comment: @Yakk thanks for the high-level view. I fell into the trap of explaining the implementation :)